# Running hciconfig in Docker container fails with Can't open HCI socket error

Tags: linux, docker, bluetooth, raspberry-pi3, hci

I have docker container based on `arm64v8/ros:humble-ros-base`.
When calling hciconfig I get:

```
root@8f3abe876714:/home/dev# hciconfig
Can't open HCI socket.: Address family not supported by protocol
```

I supposed it is a problem with mounting some volumes or privileges but I run container with command:

```
docker run -it  -v /etc:/etc -v /var:/var -v /dev:/dev -v /sys:/sys -v /run:/run --privileged --net=host  --cap-add=NET_ADMIN --cap-add=NET_RAW --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN  <my_image>
```

Does anybody know what have I forgot about? Is there any other directory that should be mounted in container to allow creating hci sockets inside docker container? Or maybe additional parameters/privileges.
When running this command on host it succeeds, problem is only in container.

Comment: are you using docker-desktop ?

Comment: No, only docker CLI

Comment: Great. Maybe you need to kill any processes on your host that use hci socket, before run your container... like bluetoothd or similar.

Comment: It seems like you're trying to disable literally every isolation feature Docker has – running a privileged container, bind-mounting a large part of the host filesystem, using host networking, enabling special capabilities.  Would it be easier to run this program with `sudo` without using a container?

Comment: I stopped bluetoothd and no other process is using hci sockets but still can't open the socket...
I'm going to limit container's privileges. I run it in privileged mode and mounted these fs parts because I'm trying to figure out this problem.

Comment: Finally I found what I missed. This was missing `--net=host` flag. Error telling that problem with address family was misleading. Thanks for your help.